# How to make an HTML Input tag return empty string when empty instead of null?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, get

I'm currently working with ASP.NET MVC and attempting to create a front-end website for my application. In this application I pass 5 fields as such via HTTP GET:

```
String1 _____ (required)
String2 _____ (default to * if empty serverside)
String3 _____
String4 _____
Integer5 ____ (String3, String4, OR Integer5 must be supplied; one or all, not none)
```

Currently, I'm attempting to validate them inside the model using data annotations such as `[Required]` and `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]` and pass defaults in the case of null. However, in the case of String2, which needs a special wildcard value if default, passing an empty string results in the model converting the null value to empty, but completely ignoring my default. I'm using `ModelState.IsValid` to enforce my viewmodel as well, and changing anything in the controller seems to be ignored by the ModelState, so IsEmptyorNull checks don't seem to work. My model looks like this:

```
    public class ProjectInput
{
    [Required]
    public string String1 { get; set; } = "0";

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string String2 { get; set; } = "****";

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string String3 { get; set; } = "";

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string String4 { get; set; } = "";

    [RegularExpression("[0-9]*")]
    public int Integer5 { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

One remedy I've found for this is to not specify the problem fields manually in the URL, which results in them using the default values I set for them, but I was not able to find a way to do this by submission without using Javascript, which I am trying to avoid along with clientside validation methods that revolve around AJAX. I also tried specifying a `Placeholder` tag of `" "` to the input tags, but this just resulted in null again.

My question restated: Is it possible, outside of using Javascript or AJAX clientside validation, to force an input tag in HTML to return a given value (instead of null) if left empty on an HTTP GET request? If not, is it possible to make a GET request leave empty submissions out of the URL?

Note that "no, you need clientside validation/Javascript" is an answer I'm willing to (heartbrokenly) accept, but I want to know if there are alternatives.

Comment: Why not just validate each param with `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` on server-side?

Comment: @user6537157 I forgot to add that I'm enforcing validation using ModelState.IsValid on the controller, which seems to ignore any changes made after the controller is called. I will add that.

Comment: Unrelated, but have you thought this through completely? How will you distinguish whether the user entered the special value or it was your script?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I don't make a distinction whether or not the user enters the value or it was the script. If the user enters it, they intend fully for the wildcard value (and they might), but if they do not, I would like it to default to the wildcard value. If you mean for debugging purposes, this application is still in early changes and has yet to go through extensive troubleshooting and QA, and as such is still being debugged. It will be logged scrutinously.

Comment: @nostalgk Good, but then I would make the user see that if they leave the input field empty, an asterix appears immediately so there would not be **two different** values (empty and asterix) for the same outcome.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius That's a great idea, thank you. I do assume that the users of my application will A. have knowledge of String2 through other applications and B. understand basic syntax used in other applications for similar uses, but that is excellent advice for the front end. I hope to use a `placeholder` in that box by default, but don't want an exception thrown if the user accidentally deletes it and changes their mind.